# xpath - how to show the anchor text of a specified link

Tags: xpath

I would like to search for a link on a page by its domain name - possibly using `contains()`? And then only show the anchor text of that link.

I've been able to get all of the a tag using

```
//a[contains(text(), 'domain_name')]
```

but unable to retrieve **just** the anchor text. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `text()` node:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'domain_name')]/text()
```

Comment: it still doesn't seem to work, will this xpath query search for the domain name in the url and then show the anchor text?

is there an issue with using a fullstop in the domain e.g. .com possibly due to it being a special character?

Comment: Oh, you want to find the domain name in its `href` attribute?